# MongoDB query for today call list

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

this is the data of one user in user table in MongoDB

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d06"),
"modified" : ISODate("2015-04-22T12:50:32.477Z"),
"name" : "Suresh",
"userId" : "sursha6398",
"created" : ISODate("2015-04-22T12:50:32.457Z"),
"deleted" : false,
"call_schedule" : [ 
    {
        "callType" : "a",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-01-14T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0e")
    }, 
    {
        "callType" : "a",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0d")
    }, 
    {
        "callType" : "b",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-02-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0c")
    }, 
    {
        "callType" : "b",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-03-02T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0b")
    }, 
    {
        "callType" : "c",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-03-17T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0a")
    }, 
    {
        "callType" : "b",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-03-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d09")
    }, 
    {
        "callType" : "a",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-08T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d08")
    }, 
    {
        "callType" : "d",
        "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-22T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d07")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

there are hundreds of users and each have one or more call scheduled. 
I need to find the total number of call scheduled for  today with corresponding userid using mongodb query.

Comment: "For today", today being variable or static (`2015/04/29`)?

Comment: for any date. I just want method how to get the call list with userID and one problem is that how to match the date without worrying about time part present in Date of Table

Comment: You could use a query using [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) to "forget" about the times. `{$and: [{"call_schedule.callDate":{ $gte: ISODate("2015-01-14T00:00:00.000Z")}}, {"call_schedule.callDate":{ $lte: ISODate("2015-01-14T23:59:59.000Z")}}]}`

Comment: how to get filtered call_schedule with userid.

Answer (score 2):

To get the total number of calls scheduled with corresponding `userid`, you need to use MongoDB's **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. The aggregation pipeline consists of a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline stage as the first step which filters the documents in the collection that have a call schedule between start of today and before tomorrow i.e. the query criteria is a date range. The next pipeline stage then uses the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator to deconstruct the `call_schedule` array so that you can get an output of a document for each element in the array. Each output document replaces the array with an element value. After the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation then filter the documents further to get only those that meet the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) criteria. The next pipeline stage would be the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator where you can then group the documents by userid and calculate the aggregated sum using the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum) operator on each document in the group. Thus your final aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
var start = new Date(); // today's date
var end = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+1));

var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "call_schedule.callDate": {
                "$gte": start,
                "$lt": end
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$call_schedule"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "call_schedule.callDate": {
                "$gte": start,
                "$lt": end
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "userId": "$userId"
            },
            "total": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }  
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "userId" : "sursha6398"
            },
            "total" : 3 // <-- this gives you the total number of calls made by userid today
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

-- **UPDATE** --

To get the filtered call schedule list, modify the `$group` pipeline stage to include the call_schedule list by using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet) method:

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+1));

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "call_schedule.callDate": {
                "$gte": today,
                "$lt": tomorrow
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$call_schedule"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "call_schedule.callDate": {
                "$gte": today,
                "$lt": tomorrow
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "userId": "$userId"
            },
            "call_list": {
                "$addToSet": "$call_schedule"
            }
        }
    }  
]);
```

With a sample collection which has the following document (that include 3 call schedules made with today's date i.e. 2015-04-29:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d06"),
    "modified" : ISODate("2015-04-22T12:50:31.477Z"),
    "name" : "Suresh",
    "userId" : "sursha6398",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-04-22T12:50:32.457Z"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "call_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "callType" : "a",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-01-14T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0e")
        }, 
        {
            "callType" : "a",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0d")
        }, 
        {
            "callType" : "b",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-02-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0c")
        }, 
        {
            "callType" : "b",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-03-02T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0b")
        }, 
        {
            "callType" : "c",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-03-17T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d0a")
        }, 
        {
            "callType" : "b",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d09")
        }, 
        {
            "callType" : "a",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d08")
        }, 
        {
            "callType" : "d",
            "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d07")
        }
    ]
}
```

The above aggregation will give the output:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "userId" : "sursha6398"
            },
            "call_list" : [ 
                {
                    "callType" : "d",
                    "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d07")
                }, 
                {
                    "callType" : "a",
                    "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d08")
                }, 
                {
                    "callType" : "b",
                    "callDate" : ISODate("2015-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d09")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: how to get filtered call_schedule with userid.

Comment: @ashish_pbh Can you at least be more explicit with your question, you asked _I need to find the total number of call scheduled for today with corresponding userid using mongodb query._ and the above returns the total number of calls scheduled for today?

Comment: as i have written in heading, i need call list means call_schedule of particular day with userid. so sry if i didn't able to clearify at first.

Comment: @ashish_pbh No worries, I have updated my answer to that effect. If possible can you please update the details in the question as well so that it becomes clearer, what the heading states clearly doesn't reflect what you ask in your question hence the ambiguity.